# Dockware with Traefik

Tags: traefik, shopware

I try to proxy a dockware container through traefik.
The error is an internal server error (500).

Is it necessary to change the domainname at all? If so, how can I change the domain name?

Docker compose for shopware

```
version: "3"

services:
  shopwaretest:
    image: dockware/play:latest
    container_name: shopwaretest
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - "db_shopwaretest:/var/lib/mysql"
       - "shopwaretest:/var/www/html"
       - ./hosts:/etc/hosts
    networks:
       - proxy
    environment:
       - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0
       - PHP_VERSION=8.0
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-http.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-http.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-http.service=shopwaretest-http-service"
      - "traefik.http.services.shopwaretest-http-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-https.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-https.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-https.service=shopwaretest-https-service"
      - "traefik.http.services.shopwaretest-https-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-https.tls=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-http.middlewares=redirect@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.shopwaretest-https.tls.certresolver=http"

volumes:
  db_shopwaretest:
    driver: local
  shopwaretest:
    driver: local

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get an internal server error, please check the server logs.

You can manually change the domain name in the `sales_channel_domain` table.

The problem might be, that SSL is terminated on traefik and Shopware does not detect this - if this is the problem, you might need to set the `TRUESTED_PROXIES` variable to the IP of your traefik server/container.